# Node.js get json post data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use express.js on my server. From my client I try to:

```
$http.post("url/send", angular.toJson(
    {
        uploads: uploads, 
        desc: desc
    }
));
```

On the server I want to read this data:

```
send function(req, res, next){

};
```

How can I extract the posted json string from the req object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Express add bodyParser middleware in configure:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});
```

And then in any request, `req.body` will contain your JSON with body data:

```
app.post('/items', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the bodyParser in your express setup like this

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true }));
});
```

Then in your route/middleware u just reed the data in req.body

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions have been deprecated in Express 4. Note that configure is no longer used to set up middleware. Secondly, bodyParser is no longer part of Express. Instead bodyParser is its own entity package and should be called separately https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser 
 the code:

```
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    });
```

is in Express 4:

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

(much simpler!)